# How can I debug Gitlab Web hooks?

Tags: gitlab, sidekiq, webhooks

I am currently using gitlab_6.9.1-omnibus-1_amd64 on a fresh install Ubuntu 12.04 in a KVM instance with dedicated WAN IP.
Everything works except web hooks. I have added every possible way of web hook adding options.

- Gitlab shows hooks with a test button which does nothing.
- I have also added global hooks via gitlab-rake but that does nothing too.
- Sidekiq runs.
- Also nothing in sidekiq log, just like gitlab-ctl - `tail` shows nothing wrong.

`# gitlab-rake gitlab:web_hook:list`

Could you please show me how I can debug web hooks on GitLab?

PS: I would like to ask this on Server Fault but I thought it must be here since it would be debugging help.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your server can reach the internet or the WebHook address, e.g. use `curl` to make a request to your WebHook Url.

If the curl request succeeded, then try to trigger your GitLab to send a WebHook request by `Test` button. If there's nothing wrong, a notification 'Hook executed successfully: HTTP 200' will appear. If there is any error, 
a notification with the error details will show up.

After you triggered the hook by push event, you can lookup into GitLab's log (in **production.log** if your environment is production), like `WebHook Error => Failed to open TCP connection to 192.168.1.1:80 (No route to host - connect(2) for "192.168.1.1" port 80)`.

If the curl request failed, try to figure out what's wrong with your network. Once the error is resolved, the GitLab WebHook requests should be successfully sent out.